# How to get index of filtered list in Swift UI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a search bar and a filtered array list that displays a list of strings. The search bar works perfectly fine and updates the list with what's contained in the search text.

The array:

`let array = ["Student 1", "Student 2", "Student 3", "Student 5","Student 6","Student 7"]`

Here is the list:

```
List {
   ForEach(array.filter{$0.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText) || searchText == ""}, id:\.self) { student in

      NavigationLink(destination: StudentSummary()){
         Text(student)

      }
   }
}
```

If the user taps on an item in the list, I want to be able to store the text of the list item that is selected into a variable, and get the index of the array in which that list item is found.

I can't find a way to keep track of which navigation link is tapped. I tried to store `student` into a variable and display it and it kept showing the last item in the list when I printed that variable. I have a feeling the navigation link is causing this issue but am not sure.

Comment: Why would you want the index. Surely you would want the student at the index, which you already have.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this test code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
let array = ["Student 1", "Student 2", "Student 3", "Student 5","Student 6","Student 7"]
@State var searchText = ""

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List {
            ForEach(array.filter{$0.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText) || searchText == ""}, id:\.self) { student in
                NavigationLink(destination: Text(self.getIndexOf(student))) {
                    Text(student)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

func getIndexOf(_ student: String) -> String {
    if let ndx = array.firstIndex(of: student) {
        return String(ndx) // or an Int if you prefer
    } else {
        return ""  // or -1
    }
}
}
```